# iconClassNameRight="muidocs-icon-navigation-expand-more" not work

Tags: material-ui

All:

I am pretty new to Material-UI, when I follow the first example in components section, the expand more icon on right side of AppBar not shown up( that down arrow ):

http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/app-bar

I have already included:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

and set style:

```
  html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  }
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That classname is from the material ui documentation website.

https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/2526

Comment: Thanks so much. It works. Could you show me how do u know this?

Answer (score 2):

You should take a different approach whether you are using Material Icons or custom SVG icons:

**Material Icons**

The solution for `Material Icons` would be to use the [**Font Icon**](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/font-icon) component within `AppBar` like below:

```
import React from 'react';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import FontIcon from 'material-ui/FontIcon';

const Header = () => (
    <AppBar
        title="Title"
        iconElementRight={<IconButton>
            <FontIcon className="material-icons">settings</FontIcon>
        </IconButton>}
    />
);

export default Header;
```

Don't forget to add `Material Icon` font in `<head>` of `index.html`:

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">`

**Custom SVG Icons**

You can use the [**SvgIcon**](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/svg-icon) component for custom SVG icons:

```
import React from 'react';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import SvgIcon from 'material-ui/SvgIcon';

const GitHubIcon = (props) => (
    <SvgIcon {...props}>
        {<path
            d="M12 .297c-6.63 0-12 5.373-12 12 0 5.303 3.438 9.8 8.205 11.385.6.113.82-.258.82-.577 0-.285-.01-1.04-.015-2.04-3.338.724-4.042-1.61-4.042-1.61C4.422 18.07 3.633 17.7 3.633 17.7c-1.087-.744.084-.729.084-.729 1.205.084 1.838 1.236 1.838 1.236 1.07 1.835 2.809 1.305 3.495.998.108-.776.417-1.305.76-1.605-2.665-.3-5.466-1.332-5.466-5.93 0-1.31.465-2.38 1.235-3.22-.135-.303-.54-1.523.105-3.176 0 0 1.005-.322 3.3 1.23.96-.267 1.98-.399 3-.405 1.02.006 2.04.138 3 .405 2.28-1.552 3.285-1.23 3.285-1.23.645 1.653.24 2.873.12 3.176.765.84 1.23 1.91 1.23 3.22 0 4.61-2.805 5.625-5.475 5.92.42.36.81 1.096.81 2.22 0 1.606-.015 2.896-.015 3.286 0 .315.21.69.825.57C20.565 22.092 24 17.592 24 12.297c0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12"/>}
    </SvgIcon>
);

const Header = () => (
    <AppBar
        title="Title"
        iconElementRight={<IconButton>
            <GitHubIcon/>
        </IconButton>}
    />
);
```

> The SvgIcon component takes an SVG path element as its child, and converts it to a React component which displays the path and allows the icon to be styled and respond to mouse events.

To obtain the `path` for popular brand icons you can use [**Simple Icons**](https://github.com/simple-icons/simple-icons). Just navigate to the raw source of the svg icon, copy its `path` part and replace it in the code as shown above.